# Calling JdbcTemplate batchUpdate() with java ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbctemplate, forkjoinpool

I was looking for a way to update a large number of rows optimally , since orm operations turned out to be slow , Eventually the solution I have used currently is to wrap the db update via jdbc batch update inside a forkjoinpool task .(With ORM it was 20 sec to update in db , with this approach it came to 5 sec)

```
ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(8);

        try {
            customThreadPool.submit(
                    () ->{
                        String query = "update tableX set name = ? ";

                        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                            @Override
                            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                             
                              //compList is a list of ABC with 50,000+ elements
                              ABC abc = compList.get(i);

                                ps.setString(1, abc.getName());
                            
                            }
                            @Override
                            public int getBatchSize() {
                                return compList.size();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    ).get();
            
            
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is it okay to do it like this ? I had seen a forkjoinpool example , however I am not sure how it is going to divide this particular db operation task.

I have tested the database changes , it is positive , but I have a couple of doubts on this :

> 1 - Are the different batches prepared operated in different threads ?
>
> 2 - I am also unsure how the db connection is managed in the multi-threaded environment

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in your code I'd like to point out.

1. It seems `jdbcTemplate` object is shared by all thread here. This essentially means sharing the same connection. We should not use the same connection in multiple threads.
2. `ForkJoinPool` is meant for recursive tasks where you need to fork out the sub-tasks and join for them to complete. I don't think is the case here. If you need to use multi-threading, use a fixed thread pool and use connection pooling to grab connection in each thread.

Comment: Thanks i’ll try that